# Checking if input raster exist or not in Raster Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, raster-calculator, map-algebra

I am with Raster Calculator in ModelBuilder on ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.

In the Raster Calculator's Map Algebra expression window, I need to check if a Raster dataset has already existed or not.

Can IsNull do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, IsNull will not check if your raster exists, it tests for NoData (null values) in an existing raster.

No, you can't check if a raster exists in the Raster Calculator.

You need a precondition in your model *before* the Raster Calculator.

See:

[Using If-Then-Else logic for branching](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/using-if-then-else-logic-for-branching.htm) (arcgis.com)

and

[If Then Else in ArcGIS model builder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68689/if-then-else-in-arcgis-model-builder) (gis.stackexchange.com)